# Show MATLAB array in a C# datagrid

Tags: c#, visual-studio, matlab

I'm making a C# app using some functions from MATLAB. 
I have developed some .dll in MATLAB and I run it on Visual Studio, one of these functions returns an array and I would like to show this data in a datagrid using C#, but I don't know how to achieve the integration.
I'll apreciate your help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's example Matlab function creating 2D array:

MATLAB code:

```
function result = mymatrix()
result = [[2,3,4]; [12,13,14];  [22,33,44]];
return;
end
```

Next convert function to .NET dll using compiler / compiler SDK toolboxes

Next reference those created DLL's and also reference MWArray.dll in C#

Here's C# code you asked for:  converting 2d array to datagrid in GridView

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //create Object from your dll
            mymatrix.Class1 MyObject = new mymatrix.Class1();

            //run the method which gets the data and save in a MWArray object
            MWArray MatlabData= MyObject.mymatrix();

            //cast the data to MWNumericArray
            MWNumericArray TableValuesMat = (MWNumericArray)MatlabData;

            // now cast to a double array   
            double[,] TableValues = (double[,])TableValuesMat.ToArray();

            // now convert 2d array to a table in gridview:
            int height = TableValues.GetLength(0);
            int width = TableValues.GetLength(1);
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnCount = width;
            for (int r = 0; r < height; r++)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
                row.CreateCells(this.dataGridView1);

                for (int c = 0; c < width; c++)
                {
                    row.Cells[c].Value = TableValues[r, c];
                }

                this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            }


        }
    }
}
```